# Can creatinine levels be lowered in dogs?

Tags: dogs, medicines

My 21-month-old Cane Corso has been diagnosed with elevated creatinine levels, they are currently at 2.2.  I have purchased a kidney function supplement, but am curious about what my success will be long term.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise in advance if I get anything wrong, because I have experience with a kidney cat, not dog, but I'll try to stick to things that should be universal.

First, about your last question. The long term effects of any treatment would depend on what your dog was diagnosed with. Elevated creatinine levels are not a diagnosis, they're a symptom. The question is: a symptom of what? Consult your vet about that. The most common things from the top of my head would be:

- Too much protein in your dog's diet

This one is simple enough. Simple diet rebalancing will do the trick.

- Too fast muscle growth and/or too much exercise and/or recent muscle damage

Self-explanatory, I think.

- Acute kidney infection
- Chronic kidney infection
- Acute kidney failure
- Chronic kidney failure

But it could be a lot of other things, really. Talk to your vet.

If it's something acute, your dog's creatinine levels will fall gradually by themselves when you deal with the cause of the problem. If it's a chronic problem though... you'll have to work with your vet closely for a long time. You'll still have to deal with the cause (how -- depends on what that is), and you'll have to deal with the toxic waste products in your dog's body that are generated when certain foods are processed and don't flush properly (that's what chronically high crea levels are about, although crea itself is not toxic). Your vet is your guide, but you can consider certain probiotics that help flush waste products through the gut, prebiotics to feed the probiotics, and certain oral adsorbents that bind with the toxins and flush together with them.